# QT6 QCanBus not decoding Frames correctly

Tags: macos, qt, can-bus, qt6

I am using a Mac and have followed the
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/macos.html & https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialbus-peakcan-overview.html documentation.

I am using `QT6.4.1 for MacOS`.

When QT receives a Can Frame it is decoding the data incorrectly.

### CAN Data On Source Device

To start with, here is the DBC file and `candump` data on the source device:

DBC file:

```
BO_ 2 Time: 2 ECU
 SG_ Minutes : 8|8@1+ (1,0) [0|0] "min" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Hours : 0|8@1+ (1,0) [0|0] "hrs" Vector__XXX

BO_ 10 GPS_SpeedTrackAlt: 8 ECU
 SG_ Altitude : 32|16@1- (0.1,0) [0|0] "Meters" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Track : 16|16@1+ (0.1,0) [0|359.9] "Degrees" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Speed : 0|16@1+ (0.1,0) [0|0] "mph" Vector__XXX

BO_ 11 GPS_Location: 8 ECU
 SG_ Longitude : 32|32@1+ (1,0) [-180|180] "Degrees" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Latitude : 0|32@1+ (1,0) [-90|90] "Degrees" Vector__XXX
```

Dump output from `candump can0` on the source device:

```
# candump can0
  can0  00A   [8]  00 00 0D 00 CE 01 00 00
  can0  00B   [8]  CA 2F 4D 42 22 66 AC BE
  can0  00A   [8]  00 00 0D 00 CE 01 00 00
  can0  00B   [8]  CA 2F 4D 42 24 66 AC BE

  ...

  can0  00A   [8]  00 00 0D 00 CC 01 00 00
  can0  00B   [8]  CB 2F 4D 42 45 66 AC BE
  can0  002   [2]  06 35
  can0  00A   [8]  00 00 0D 00 CD 01 00 00
  can0  00B   [8]  CB 2F 4D 42 49 66 AC BE
```

As you can see the CAN Data being generated matched the DBC file, the data is also successfully received and decoded by other applications.

### On My Mac

The data is correctly displayed when receiving the CAN Data via Python or the **MacCAN Monitor** tool. The IDs are correct, the payload length is correct and the data is correct. (The actual payload will vary slightly over time and therefore the actual data within the payload varies slightly, but the shape of the data is consistent.)

Python Output:

```
ID=00A LEN=8 DATA=[00 00 47 0A 6E 02 00 00]
ID=00B LEN=8 DATA=[E9 2F 4D 42 0E 67 AC BE]
ID=00A LEN=8 DATA=[00 00 47 0A 6D 02 00 00]
ID=00B LEN=8 DATA=[E9 2F 4D 42 28 66 AC BE]
ID=002 LEN=2 DATA=[06 3A 00 00 00 00 00 00]
ID=00A LEN=8 DATA=[00 00 47 0A 6A 02 00 00]
ID=00B LEN=8 DATA=[EA 2F 4D 42 CA 65 AC BE]
ID=00A LEN=8 DATA=[00 00 47 0A 6E 02 00 00]
```

Output from MacCan Monitor
[MacCAN Monitor Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmd9V.png)

**QT Output**

This is the debug output from Qt `qDebug() << canFrame.toString() << " Payload: " << canFrame.payload();`

```
"0000000A   [6]  E3 00 00 00 00 00"  Payload:  "\xE3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"     00B  [66]  Remote Request"  Payload:  "\x06^\xAC\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xC4\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x10/!\x00\x00`\x00\x00)\x00@\xFF""e>'\xB8\n\x00\x00 E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"0000000A   [6]  E3 00 00 00 00 00"  Payload:  "\xE3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"     00B  [66]  Remote Request"  Payload:  "\x06^\xAC\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xC4\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x10/!\x00\x00`\x00\x00)\x00@\xFF""e>'\xB8\n\x00\x00 E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"     002   [0]"  Payload:  ""
"0000000A   [6]  E3 00 00 00 00 00"  Payload:  "\xE3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"     00B  [66]  Remote Request"  Payload:  "\x07^\xAC\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xC4\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x10/!\x00\x00`\x00\x00)\x00@\xFF""e>'\xB8\n\x00\x00 E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"0000000A   [6]  E3 00 00 00 00 00"  Payload:  "\xE3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"     00B  [66]  Remote Request"  Payload:  "\x07^\xAC\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xC4\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x10/!\x00\x00`\x00\x00)\x00@\xFF""e>'\xB8\n\x00\x00 E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"0000000A   [6]  E3 00 00 00 00 00"  Payload:  "\xE3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"     00B  [66]  Remote Request"  Payload:  "\t^\xAC\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xC4\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x10/!\x00\x00`\x00\x00)\x00@\xFF""e>'\xB8\n\x00\x00 E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"0000000A   [6]  E4 00 00 00 00 00"  Payload:  "\xE4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

As you can see the output from QT is different from expected, the Frame IDs are correct:

| Frame ID | Expected Extended Id | Expected Length | QT Extended Id | QT Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x02 | No | 2 | No | 0 |
| 0x0A | No | 8 | Yes | 66 |
| 0x0B | No | 8 | No | 6 |

I have tried other CAN sources and see the same issue.

Here is the code I am running that reproduces the problem and the debug output:

**CanBusTest.pro**

```
QT += quick serialbus

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS = x86_64 arm64
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QCanBus>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class FrameReceiver : public QObject {
  public:
    FrameReceiver(QObject *parent = nullptr, QCanBusDevice *device = nullptr) {
        this->device = device;
        connect(device, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, this, &FrameReceiver::onNewFrame);
    }
  public slots:
    void onNewFrame(void) {
        while (this->device->framesAvailable()) {
            QCanBusFrame canFrame = this->device->readFrame();
            qDebug() << canFrame.toString() << " Payload: " << canFrame.payload();

        }
    }

  private:
    QCanBusDevice *device;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString errorString;
    QCanBusDevice *device =
        QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(QStringLiteral("peakcan"), QStringLiteral("usb0"), &errorString);

    device->setConfigurationParameter(QCanBusDevice::BitRateKey, QVariant::fromValue(250000));
    qDebug() << "Can Device: " << device;
    device->connectDevice();

    FrameReceiver *frameReceiver = new FrameReceiver(nullptr, device);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/CanBusTest/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
        [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong on your output? I can see a sequence of 0x0a,0x0b, 0x02, 0x0a,0x0b, 0x0a,0x0b also in your image

Comment: @chehrlic I have added the payload the Qt is getting which differs from the expected that is in the screen grab.

Comment: The output from the first and second does not match so how should we believe it's the one matching to your screenshot? Also your example code doesn't have the print routines so we don't know how you try to print it.

Comment: HI @chehrlic, I have tied to show more clearly what I am expecting and what I am getting from QT. I have made the QT output match the code, and have tied to to assume anything. The CAN data will never exactly match, as the payload varies over time. However, there are only 3 Frame IDs 0x02, 0x0A, and 0x0B... I have included the DBC file to help.   Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In case others find this issue; I have now run the code on a Windows machine and the CAN Frames are decoded correctly, therefore I have raised a bug report with Qt:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-113538